Building react app with github actions then pushing build to digital ocean apps
I am trying to build my react app on github actions then deploy it to digital oceans app platform. It keeps building but doesn't seem to actually be making changes, here is my actions script. I'm also not even sure this is possible

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CI: false
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '20'
      - name: Cache dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build
      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy to DigitalOcean App Platform
        run: doctl apps create-deployment ${{ secrets.PROD_APP_ID }}


Try changing the DigitalOcean run command to doctl apps update PROD_APP_ID --spec .do/app.yaml
Make sure you have the .yaml file in your repository, that specifies the configuration for your DO deployment.
Code:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CI: false
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '20'
      - name: Cache dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build
      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy to DigitalOcean App Platform
        env:
          DO_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        run: doctl apps update ${{ secrets.PROD_APP_ID }} --spec .do/app.yaml

And here's and example for the app.yaml file:
name: my-react-app
services:
  - name: web
    github:
      repo: github-username/repo-name
      branch: main
      deploy_on_push: true
    build_command: npm run build
    run_command: npx serve -s build
    source_dir: /
    environment_slug: node-js
    http_port: 8080
    routes:
      - path: /
    instance_count: 1
    instance_size_slug: basic-xxs
    envs:
      - key: NODE_ENV
        value: production


Couple things on this, wouldn't you want deploy_on_push to be false? because you want github to force the push. Secondly whats the idea behind setting the build_command if github is supposed to be handling that?

I think you can use ssh-deploy to deploy your react app on Digital ocean. I provide sample code I used in my react web application.
name: Build & Deploy Gallerai on server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  REACT_APP_API_URL: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_API_URL }}
  REACT_APP_PUBLIC_NFT_STORAGE_API_KEY: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_NFT_STORAGE_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_STRIPE_ESSENTIAL_ID: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_STRIPE_ESSENTIAL_ID }}
  REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRO_LITE_ID: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRO_LITE_ID }}
  REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRO_ID: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRO_ID }}
  REACT_APP_GIPHY_SDK_API_KEY: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_GIPHY_SDK_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_TINYMCE_API_KEY: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_TINYMCE_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_EMAIL_REDIRECT_LINK: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_EMAIL_REDIRECT_LINK }}
  REACT_APP_CLOUDFLARE_WORKER_TOKEN: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_CLOUDFLARE_WORKER_TOKEN }}
  REACT_APP_TRUNSTILE_SITE_KEY: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_TRUNSTILE_SITE_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_DISCORD_CLIENT_ID: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_DISCORD_CLIENT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI }}
  REACT_APP_DISCORD_SCOPE: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_DISCORD_SCOPE }}
  REACT_APP_DISCORD_TYPE: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_DISCORD_TYPE }}

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    name: Build & Deploy Gallerai on server
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run build
        run: npm run build --if-present
    
      - name: Deploy on server
        uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main
        with:
            SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
            ARGS: "-rlgoDzvc -i --delete"
            SOURCE: "build/"
            REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_HOST }}
            REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_USER }}
            REMOTE_PORT: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_PORT }}
            TARGET: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_TARGET }}
            EXCLUDE: "/dist/, /node_modules/"


Is this droplet server or apps server?

It's app server created by Linode. But there is no problem even if you use ubuntu server from Digital ocean. The most important thing is that you access the server via SSH.

You can't open an ssh connection to digital ocean apps

Oh, sorry. what do you mean? You can definetely access digitalocean apps server via SSH.

I'm not sure if you are getting it confused with their droplets but their app platform is fully managed by them and they do no allow ssh as a type of access to your system.
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/details/limits/
"You cannot open SSH or SFTP ports on App Platform containers. You must deploy code changes through your code repository or container image."
